# Redux, Redux, and websocket middleware: respond to actions with actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've got a websocket middleware, and I'd like to dispatch an action in response to another action which the middleware dispatches, specifically after the websocket achieved a connection.

I know you shouldn't dispatch action inside a reducer, but I can't find a good place to react to the middleware actions.

Is there a conventional way to dispatch an action is response to another action?

Comment: If you've written a middleware for websockets, ideally the middleware should expose an api to dispatch the actions. Take a look at how redux-saga has implemented [put](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#putaction) for dispatching actions.

Comment: You could make use of redux-thunk middleware which allows you to dispatch an action from within another action